# "Elegant" way to get list of list of property values from List<T> of objects?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Say I have a `Customer` class with the usual properties: `CustomerID`, `Name`, etc.

As a result of a query, I get a generic list of Customer objects: `List<Customer>`

Is there an elegant way to get an array/list of CustomerID or Name property values from this generic list? (i.e. string[] customerIDs = ???? )

I know I could do a `foreach` and fill an array during the loop, but was just wondering if there were a more elegant way through LINQ extensions and/or lambda expressions to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using LINQ, you can do the following:

```
string[] customerIDs = list.Select(x => x.ID).ToArray();
```

Comment: Is there a way to do something similar without LINQ? It is not available for me at the moment since we're still using C# 2.0.

Comment: there's no "elegant" way to do it. You need to make a new array of the right size, and one-by-one fill it up in a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
List customerList = GetCustomerList();

var customerIDs =
    from c in customerList 
    select c.CustomerID;
```

More samples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336758.aspx#SelectSimple2).